# how to remove extra blank spaces from rdlc?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, rdlc, rdl

I'm having .net 2.0 version with VS 2005. I'm using rdlc which is having a matrix to generate excel report data. I need to group records based on Date column. I'm wondering why its generating extra blank spaces in the output excel report?

Here is the rdlc,

[image]

Excel Output having blank spaces  as highlighted below:

[image]

am I missing to configure some properties in rdlc?

I have also tried to set the visibility property of the column using,

1.=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Title.Value),False,True)

2.=IIF(Len(Fields!Title.Value) = 0,False,True)

Both didn't work :(

Comment: What exactly is the desired behavior?  My best guess is that you wish to remove the empty cells by moving the data up, but it's not completely clear in your description. And I can't really tell what exactly is the cause of the empty cells. So could you share your datasource layout?

Comment: Yes, need to remove the empty cells by moving the data up. data source is just a list containing Date and Title. that doesn't have any empty records